# Angular event on images all rendered

Tags: angularjs

To avoid ugly screen redraw on a slow platform, I'm attempting to detect an event when all images have rendered (rather than just loaded) from either a directive or a controller.  I haven't managed to find an appropriate event.

I guess I could wait for the '$viewContentLoaded' event and then trigger a $timeout to activate ng-show after an arbitrary period of time but that's clearly hacky.  Is there a better solution?

```
.directive ( 'myDirective', ['$window',

function ( $window ) {

    return {

        link: function ( $scope, $element, $attr ) {

            $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
                alert ('$viewContentLoaded!')
                $timeout(function () {
                    // show content
                },1000);

            });
    }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### This is a simplified version of what I use

Assuming you use jquery along with angular:

```
app.directive('imagesLoaded',[function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var $img = element.find("img"),
          count = $img.length,
          i = 0;

      if( count === 0) return;

      $img.one("load", function(){
        i++;
        if (i >= count) {
          scope.$broadcast('images.loaded');
        }
      });

      $img.each(function(){
        if (this.complete) {
          $(this).load(); // needed for cached images
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the response but I specifically need to detect when the images have finished rendering, not loading.