# imagesLoaded Plugin not working with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, image

So i'm learning AngularJS and i'm building a small web app that allows you to click through images randomly. Basically you click the next button and an image is downloaded and shown, when you click the back button it goes to the previous image in the stack.

I'd like to show a loading spinner and disable the back/forward buttons until the ajax request for the new image is complete, AND the image is completely loaded

My image controller is structured like so:

```
app.controller('ImageController', ['imageService', function(imageService) {
    var that = this;
    that.position = 0;
    that.images = [];
    that.loading = false;

    that.isLoading = function() {
        return that.loading;
    }

    that.setLoading = function(isLoading) {
        that.loading = isLoading;
    }

    that.currentImage = function() {
        if (that.images.length > 0) {
            return that.images[that.position];
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    };

    that.fetchSkin = function() {
        that.setLoading(true);
        imageService.fetchRandomSkin().success(function(data) {
            // data is just a js object that contains, among other things, the URL for the image I want to display.
            that.images.push(data);

            that.imagesLoaded = imagesLoaded('.skin-preview-wrapper', function() {
                console.log('images loaded');
                that.setLoading(false);
            });
        });
    };

    that.nextImage = function() {
        that.position++;
        if (that.position === that.images.length) {
            that.fetchSkin();
        }
    };

    that.previousImage = function() {
        if (that.position > 0) {
            that.position--;
        }
    };

    that.fetchSkin();
}]);
```

If you notice inside of the that.fetchSkin() function, i'm calling the imagesLoaded plugin then when the images are loaded I am setting that.loading to false. In my template I am using ng-show to show the images when the loading variable is set to false.

If I set loading to false outside of the imagesLoaded callback (like when the ajax request is complete) then everything works as expected, when I set it inside of the imagesLoaded function the template doesn't update with the new loading value. Note that the console.log('images loaded'); does print to the console once the images have loaded so I know the imagesLoaded plugin is working correctly.

Comment: maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037292/angular-event-on-images-all-rendered/23037436#23037436

Comment: Make that.loading local, otherwise having getters and setters is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `imagesLoaded` callback is invoked asynchronously once images are loaded, Angular does not know that values of `that.isLoading()` method calls changed. It is because of dirty checking that Angular uses to provide you with easy to use 2 way data binding.

If you have a template like so:
`<div ng-show="isLoading()"></div>`

it won't update after you change the values.

You need to manually tell angular about data changes and that can be done by invoking $digest manually.

```
$scope.$digest();
```

just after you do

```
 console.log('images loaded');
 that.setLoading(false);
```

Pseudo code that can work (copied and pasted from my directive):

```
//inside your controller
$scope.isLoading = false;

// just another way of using imagesLoaded. Yours is ok.
$element.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

As long as you only change your controller $scope within async callback, there's no need to call `$apply()` to run $digest on $rootScope because your model changes are only local.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, I figured it was something about angular that I just didn't fully understand.

Comment: No worries, although it took me a while to fully understand how angular works as well. Again, stack overflow explanations of $digest and dirty checking FTW! On a side note - if you will grab source code of Angular and go to `ngClick` directive implementation, you will see that they do $scope.$apply() as well because browser events (onClick, onMouseLeave and so on) are async as well :)

Comment: I was searching around for a half hour why my ng-if wasn't working, was same reason, needed to run $scope.digest() after updating the value.